# What IP Address should I use for querying MySQL DB from Lambda Functions across AWS Site-to-Site VPN?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've built out an AWS architecture that utilizes two regions:

**First Region:**
VPC which contains Lambda functions, an attached internet gateway, an attached Virtual Private Gateway, configured Customer Gateway, and a configured Site-to-Site VPN connection. This region also has API Gateway setup, which is paired with those lambda functions, but respectfully not within the VPC. This VPC uses the CIDR block `10.100.0.0/16`.

**Second Region:**
VPC which contains an EC2 (AMI) instance, acting as our Customer Gateway, and also has MySQL running. I used `bind-address` as my private EC2 IP address (`10.200.0.245`). This VPC uses the CIDR block `10.200.0.0/16`.

I'm trying to decipher what IP address I should give access to through MySQL permissions, to allow my Lambda functions from the first region to send a SQL query to MySQL running in the second region. Would my Lambda function be auto-assigned an IP address under its CIDR block? Does a VPG have an IP address that I'm missing?

Comment: I may be wrong, but shouldnt you have a master and a read replica of some sort w/ a relational distributed db architecture? you would always want to write to master and read from replica. Lambda, when used w/ VPC configurations, will spin up and attach an ENI dynamically, thus attaching you to your VPC.

Comment: I should have prefaced this better — my goal is to prove out what an architecture might look like with querying an on-prem DB via Lambda functions. So I've tried to avoid RDS as much as possible with testing, since we wouldn't be migrating any data to cloud databases. The EC2 is meant to "act" like an on-prem Datacenter for this first iteration.

Comment: still not sure what you are going after. Your configurations for on Prem will not be within a VPC, they will have their own subnet that is unique, but outside of a VPCs. your lambda, once attached to VPC and assuming your networking is all correct (ie firewalls) can call your on prem DB. This connection, I would give a hostname so if the IPs ever change, their is no need to update env. vars or redeploy code

Comment: You can't predict (or assign) individual Lambda IP addresses. You might want to carve out a subnet just for the Lambdas so that at least you predict, and can whitelist, the subnet's CIDR.